# indexOf() + 1 vs indexOf() != -1

Tags: javascript

When checking for existence of a substring I have been doing this:

```
var that = "ok hello cool";    
if( that.indexOf('hello') + 1 ) {
}
```

Instead of:

```
if( that.indexOf('hello') != -1 ) {
}
```

Am I overlooking something or is there a reason not to do this.

**Update:**

Yes, I was indeed unaware of the even simpler method of:

```
if ( ~that.indexOf( 'hello' ) ) {

}
```

You can read about the `~` bitwise operator and the other queer bitwise operators here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: `if( ~that.indexOf('hello') )` is usually used

Comment: What's wrong with `indexOf(...) >= 0`?

Comment: @RussellBorogove Nothing. It's totally valid. `~` is a lot cleaner than `>= 0`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the most seen way:

```
if ( ~that.indexOf( 'hello' ) ) {
}
```

The `~` operator does some magic and transforms only -1 in 0, thus it's the only falsy value.

Comment: That is neat, never seen that.

Comment: @Florian [MDN says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) Inverts the bits of its operand. WTH does that mean?

Comment: Ok, that's not really important to understand here. All you need to understand is that `~-1 === 0` (false for not found) and `~anythingelse !== 0` (true for found)

Comment: @iambriansreed It's working on the bits of the number. For example, 2 in base 10 is 0010 in base 2. Well, ~ inverts all the bits. But yeah, as Esailija says, it's not really important to know, you probably won't ever use it except for this case.

Comment: @iambriansreed it seems to be 1-s complement -(1+x)

Comment: I doubt this could be called the "most seen way", like GeorgeMauer and iambriansreed, I haven't seen this before either.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, I believe you mean 2's complement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: @Izkata Should I say "most used by experienced js dev"? :-) It's even mentioned in [one of the best js tutorials](http://javascript.info/tutorial/string#finding-a-substring) out there.

Comment: I think that this not the best way to make code readable. Why using bitwise operator to create a condition? `!= -1` is used in many languages and it is the simplest and most readable method.

Answer (score 13):

Well, I believe the second one is more obvious what's going on...

```
if( that.indexOf('hello') != -1 ) {
}
```

That's all to it however, both expressions are valid and perfectly ok.